# The date in the server response is different from the date in the database FastAPI, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

**I I wrote a simple function that should return records from my database (potsgres)**

```
 async def all_message(self, chat_id: int) -> List[MessageAll]:
    query = message.select().where(message.c.chat_id == chat_id).order_by(desc(message.c.date_send))
    return await self.database.fetch_all(query)
```

**my endpoint**

```
    @mes_router.get('/{chat_id}')
async def get_message_for_chat(
        chat_id: int,
        message: MessageRepository = Depends(get_message_repository),
):
    return await message.all_message(chat_id=chat_id)
```

**my model**

```
  class MessageAll(BaseModel):
    id: int
    message: str
    date_send: d
    chat_id: int
    sender_id: int
```

**However, the time in my database is different from the time I get in response from the server**

**EXAMPLE**

database entry(Its True)

- message: hello
- date: 2023-01-15 01:49:06.535 +0300

response from the server(Its False)

- message:hello
- date: 2023-01-14T22:49:06.535436+00:00

**How can I display the correct time in the response from the server?**

Comment: They are the same time, note the time zone offsets.

Comment: What @AdrianKlaver said. Also, I hope your database entries are actually stored in UTC.